# Azure Site recovery Disk Size Unsupported but less than 1TB in size

Tags: azure

Unable to add a virtual machine to Azure Site Recovery.  Other machines are setup and functioning in the Vault that is setup.  Here is a link to the thread I posted on MS site with steps and additional info I completed: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce19698b-b482-47a8-a66c-6ff07e899591/disk-size-unsupported-but-less-than-1tb-in-size-unable-to-add-to-asr?forum=hypervrecovmgr

Essentially I'm unable to add the VM to Azure Site recovery with the error message disk size unsupported.  I've verified that the disk is basic and less than 1TB but will not pass the discovery to add the server.  Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue. For anyone else who may experience the issue I'm posting my resolution.  The root cause of the issue was due to a vss provider on the server being in a failed state.  The SQL Service Writer Vss provider had failed.  We fixed the installation of SQL addressing the SQL Service Writer vss provider and were able to then add the server to ASR successfully.